# I get nothing by calling `api.query.contracts.contractInfoOf`

Tags: ink

I get nothing by using `api.query.contracts.contractInfoOf`, I'm working with a local substrate node. And I'm able to see my deployed contract at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/contracts .

[image]

```
import {ApiPromise, WsProvider, Keyring } from '@polkadot/api';

const wsProvider = new WsProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:9944");
const api = await ApiPromise.create();
const res = await api.query.contracts.contractInfoOf("5CNcbf4FDSgzJ7pBMpe1gxRkndXEK9thRtCjb1fHFbhRwK57");
console.log(res.registry);
```

The result is `TypeRegistry {}`.

Is this situation reasonable?
Can `query.contracts.contractInfoOf` get the ABI of deployed contract?

I'm a beginner at substrate and ink!...

Answer (score 1):

Each API result object has a `registry` - this is the built-in API registry, which is what you are logging there.

The [contractInfoOf](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#contractinfoofaccountid32-optionpalletcontractsstoragerawcontractinfo) returns an `Option< PalletContractsStorageRawContractInfo>`, which is not the ABI (this is never uploaded, only kept locally).

If you are interested in what `PalletContractsStorageRawContractInfo` contains, [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/dbfb03760c4d1c60dae31ac61456b04bf9e1c26a/packages/types-augment/src/lookup/types-substrate.ts#L4218-L4222) is a TypeScript representation as extracted from the Substrate master metadata.

It contains the `trieId`, `codeHash` as `storageDeposit` fields.